# Adding a listener that fires whenever the user changes tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension and trying to get a function to fire everytime the user changes tab. I've been looking at the listeners in the webRequest API, and the chrome.tabs but couldn't figure what to use, and what not to use.

The only information I need from the tab is its url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated):

> Fires when the active tab in a window changes. Note that the tab's URL
>   may not be set at the time this event fired, but you can listen to
>   onUpdated events to be notified when a URL is set.
>   
>   — [Google Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated)

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
        mySuperCallback(tab.url);
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, updatedTab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (activeTabs) {
        var activeTab = activeTabs[0];

        if (activeTab == updatedTab) {
            mySuperCallback(activeTab.url);
        }
    });
});

function mySuperCallback(newUrl) {
    // ...
}
```

It definitely works in background pages (as Locercus confirmed in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162644/adding-a-listener-that-fires-whenever-the-user-changes-tab/18162817?noredirect=1#comment26607619_18162817)), but please consider using [event pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) (stable since Chrome 22) instead.

Comment: I took a look at it. But how would i go around getting the URL, when it has been set. I need to get the event to fire whenever you go to a new URL in your active tab, too.

Comment: @Locercus Use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) and check whether the changed tab is the active tab in the current window *and* whether the URL has been changed .

Comment: Could you give me an example in a context? Where'd I place the onActivated listener? I'm pretty sure it won't work in popup.js

Comment: @Locercus This should actually work in a background script and in your popup (though I'm not 100% sure. I haven't developed chrome exts for a while now).

Comment: So you're telling me that I can put this in either popup.html or background.html?

Comment: @Locercus Just try it ;) As I said, I'm not 100% sure and I cannot find documentation about that right now.

Comment: **Note to future readers**: It works if you put it in background.js and use the background feature in manifest.json. Take a look at this page. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html

Comment: Great explanation and nice code. Thanks.
When I run this, however, it never drops into the mySuperCallback routine. Any thoughts?